# Sql query slower in azure data bricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Am running the following SQL query in Azure Data Bricks using SQL notebook it runs for 40 seconds while the same query runs with in 4 seconds in Azure DB.How to make the query to run faster in Azure Data Bricks.I have used the below method to connect the table between Azure DB and Data Bricks

```
-- Create Table
CREATE TABLE SalesRep
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
url 'jdbc:sqlserver://#SERVERNAME#.database.windows.net:1433;database=AdventureWorksLT',
dbtable 'SalesLT.SalesRep',
user '#USERNAME#',
password "#PASSWORD#"
);
```

Sql query

```
select  i.*
FROM 
Invoice I
INNER JOIN InvoiceLineItem ILT  ON I.InvoiceRecordId=ILT.InvoiceRecordId   
INNER JOIN part ON part.[parent part]=ILT.PartNumber
WHERE
part.[item nbr] ='12X-33-xx'
```

Can we create index in Azure Data Bricks since the query running in azure db is using the index the query is faster is there any alternatives to index in azure data bricks or is there any other reason for the slow performance in data bricks

```
Cluster configuration
Databricks Runtime Version
4.1 (includes Apache Spark 2.3.0, Scala 2.11)
Python Version
3
Driver Type
28.0 GB Memory, 8 Cores, 1.5 DBU Standard_DS4_v2
Worker Type
112.0 GB Memory, 16 Cores, 4 DBU Standard_DS14_v2
Min Workers
1
Max Workers
15
```

Comment: The query is executed on the SQL DB side so the actual runtime is probably identical. It's just that Databricks has to schedule the job/tasks which is overhead. This isn't the type of query you would expect to see in Spark. Generally you would get all the data from each table you need - then process as dataframes in Spark.

Comment: @_simon_i_dm am new to databricks, Did the query uses the index for selection. so if I convert all the table in to data frames and then process, will it be faster?

Comment: It will uses indexes in the SQL database if they exist. It the same as executing a query from any application.

Comment: How the data frames will help in speeding the process